# Script to rotate pages in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, acrobat

In Javascript for Adobe Acrobat DC, I know about getPageRotation and setPageRotations, but the command looks like it needs a specific page range. How could I rotate every page that is at 90 degrees, to 270 degrees? That is, rotate all pages that should be landscape, to landscape? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

That should do what you want for all pages in a PDF, page bei page:

```
for (var i = 0;i < this.numPages; i++){
    r = getPageRotation(i);
    if (r == 90) setPageRotations(i,i,270);
}
```